# Unable to fetch data in recycler view using Retrofit2 + RxJava2

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I am using retrofit2 for making network request I am trying to fetch data from server in recycler view for taht I using RxJava implementation but data is not  fetching though it is showing Log message on onNext() method.

Below is my code:

**ApiService.java**

```
public interface ApiService {

    @POST("retrofitUsers")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Observable<String> saveData(@Field("name") String name,
                             @Field("age") String age)

    @GET("getUsers")
    Flowable<List<BioData>> getData();

}
```

**RetrofitClient.java**

```
public class RetrofitClient {

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getInstance() {
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(22,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(22, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(22, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

        if(retrofit == null)
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://example.com/")
                .addConverterFactory(
                    GsonConverterFactory
                        .create(
                            new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()
                        )
                )
                .addCallAdapterFactory(
                    RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create()
                )
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();

        return retrofit;
    }

    private RetrofitClient() {
    }
}
```

**BioData.java**

```
public class BioData {

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("age")
    @Expose
    private String age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

**Users.java**

```
public class Users extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recycle;
    UserAdapter adapter;
    ProgressBar prog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_users);

        prog = findViewById(R.id.prog);

        recycle = findViewById(R.id.recycle);
        recycle.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recycle.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        fetchData();
     }

     private void fetchData() {

         Retrofit retrofit  = RetrofitClient.getInstance();
         ApiService myApi = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);

         myApi.getData()
             .toObservable()
             .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
             .subscribe(new Observer<List<BioData>>() {

                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(List<BioData> bioData) {

                    if(bioData.size() > 0){
                        Log.d("Data","Hello");
                    }
                    adapter = new UserAdapter(bioData,getApplicationContext());
                    recycle.setAdapter(adapter);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            });
      }

}
```

Someone please let me know what's the problem why data is not displaying.Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you're trying to manipulate with recycler view and its adapter from another thread. Just try to add method `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` in Rx chain after `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())`

Also, remove from `onNext()` these lines:

```
adapter = new UserAdapter(bioData, getApplicationContext());
recycle.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Please, init your adapter earlier (when you're initializing recycler view) and pass inside adapter empty list, after that set this previously initialized adapter to recycler view. Then, inside `onNext()` set fetched list from server to adapter and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

The code example you can see below:

```
adapter = new UserAdapter(new ArrayList<BioData>(), getApplicationContext());

recycle = findViewById(R.id.recycle);
recycle.setHasFixedSize(true);
recycle.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

recycle.setAdapter(adapter);
...
```

Then `onNext()`:

```
if(bioData.size() > 0){
    Log.d("Data","Hello");
}
adapter.setData(bioData, getApplicationContext());
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Of course, you need to declare `setData(List<BioData>)` method in your `UserAdapter`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, bro now its working fine actually I forgot to add observeOn() method.

Comment: @Digvijay you're welcome! Please mark it as an answer if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Instead of OnNext, try to implement below method

```
private void loadJSON() {

    RequestInterface requestInterface = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build().create(RequestInterface.class);

    mCompositeDisposable.add(requestInterface.register()
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(this::handleResponse,this::handleError));
}

private void handleResponse(List<Android> androidList) {

    mAndroidArrayList = new ArrayList<>(androidList);
    mAdapter = new DataAdapter(mAndroidArrayList);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

Please Check below link 
https://www.learn2crack.com/2016/11/android-rxjava-2-and-retrofit.html